# Sysbench - Public key for postgresql-libs-9.2.24-7.el7_9.x86_64.rpm is not installed

Tags: mysql, mariadb, redhat

I have a `mariadb` on a `redhat server (7.9)` and trying to install `sysbench` for benchmarking with this command:

```
sudo yum -y install sysbench
```

I got this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fusioninventory-agent, product-id, rhnplugin, search-disabled-repos
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package sysbench.x86_64 0:1.0.17-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libck.so.0()(64bit) for package: sysbench-1.0.17-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libluajit-5.1.so.2()(64bit) for package: sysbench-1.0.17-2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpq.so.5()(64bit) for package: sysbench-1.0.17-2.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ck.x86_64 0:0.5.2-2.el7 will be installed
---> Package luajit.x86_64 0:2.0.4-3.el7 will be installed
---> Package postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:9.2.24-7.el7_9 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                       Arch                                 Version                                       Repository                                                    Size
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 sysbench                                      x86_64                               1.0.17-2.el7                                  rhel-x86_64-7-epel-20220531                                  152 k
Installing for dependencies:
 ck                                            x86_64                               0.5.2-2.el7                                   rhel-x86_64-7-epel-20220531                                   26 k
 luajit                                        x86_64                               2.0.4-3.el7                                   rhel-x86_64-7-epel-20220531                                  343 k
 postgresql-libs                               x86_64                               9.2.24-7.el7_9                                rhel-x86_64-7-updates-20220531                               235 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total size: 756 k
Installed size: 2.3 M
Downloading packages:
warning: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7Server/rhel-x86_64-7-updates-20220531/packages/postgresql-libs-9.2.24-7.el7_9.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY


Public key for postgresql-libs-9.2.24-7.el7_9.x86_64.rpm is not installed
```

And I don't unterstand why it can't find the key.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The OS can't find the key. The long and more basic way is to go to the path it pointed out and find the key.

The easiest way is to ignore it and use this command:

```
sudo yum -y install sysbench --nog
```